# Ruby on rails display star images for the rating system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, rating, rating-system

I have a simple rails application where a user can leave a rating for a product and at the minute I have it so that the average rating is displayed on the index page, so for the book Animal Farm if there are the ratings: 1, 3, 5 the index will display 3 for that book. But what I want to do is replace the number displayed with stars, so rather than showing "star rating: 3" it will show "star rating:" then three star images. Is there a quick and simple way of doing this?

/views/products/index.html.erb:

```
<div id="star-rating">
        <% if not product.no_of_stars.blank? %>
          Star rating: <%= product.no_of_stars %>
        <% else %>
          <%= link_to 'Please add a Review',{ controller: 'reviews', action: 'new', id: product.id } %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
```

/models/product.rb:

```
def no_of_stars
    self.reviews.average('no_of_stars')
end
```

I also need to know where to save the image of a star and how to select that star to be displayed, so far I have it in the /app/assets/images directory. I need to do this purely in ruby without java.

Can someone please help, I am fairly new to ruby so could do with a complete breakdown of what to do? Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a helper. In case you need the stars in different models you can add a helper in the file `app/helpers/application_helper.rb` (I use '*' as a representation for a star):

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def render_stars(value)
    output = ''
    if (1..5).include?(value.to_i)
      value.to_i.times { output += '*'}
    end
    output
  end

end
```

Your refactored view would look like this:

```
<div id="star-rating">
  <% if product.no_of_stars.blank? %>
    <%= link_to 'Please add a Review',{ controller: 'reviews', action: 'new', id: product.id } %>
  <% else %>
    Star rating: <%= render_stars(product.no_of_stars) %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: I've just tried that literally as it is without adapting any of your code and get the following error:

NoMethodError in Products#index

Showing C:/Sites/week_15_test/1/Under Construction/my_bookshop_test2/app/views/products/index.html.erb where line #35 raised:

undefined method `times' for #<BigDecimal:6dbed90,'0.2E1',9(45)>

Extracted source (around line #35):
 
<% if product.no_of_stars.blank? %>
<%= link_to 'Please add a Review',{ controller: 'reviews', action: 'new', id: product.id } %>
<% else %>
Star rating: <%= render_stars(product.no_of_stars) %>
<% end %>
</div>

Comment: @benjs.1 it's complaining that you can't call `times` on `BigDecimal`s.

Comment: Is there a way of doing it to get half a star, for example for 4.5?

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer and post a second question for the 4.5 half star problem.

Comment: Thank you, here is the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27888515/ruby-on-rails-display-half-a-star-for-a-decimal-rating-e-g-4-5