# Ruby on Rails display half a star for a decimal rating, e.g. 4.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, rating, rating-system

I am able to view 5 asterisks for a rating of 5 for a product, and 4 asterisks for a rating of 4 etc. But what I would like to do is replace the asterisks with an image of a star that I have in my assets/images/ directory, and if a rating is of 4.5 then display half a star. Is there a way of doing this? Below is my current code in application_helper.rb and the view in index.html.erb.

application_helper.rb:

```
module ApplicationHelper
   def render_stars(value)
      output = ''
      if (1..5).include?(value.to_i)
         value.to_i.times { output += '*'}
      end
      output
   end
end
```

index.html.erb:

```
<div id="star-rating">
    <% if not product.no_of_stars.blank? %>
        <div id="star-rating">
    <% if product.no_of_stars.blank? %>
       <%= link_to 'Please add a Review',{ controller: 'reviews', action: 'new', id: product.id } %>
     <% else %>
        Star rating: <%= render_stars(product.no_of_stars) %>
    <% end %>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume you want to use `star.gif` as a star image and `half-star.gif` as the 1/2 star image:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def render_stars(value)
    output = ''
    if (1..5).include?(value.floor)
      value.floor.times { output += image_tag('star.gif')}
    end
    if value == (value.floor + 0.5) && value.to_i != 5
      output += image_tag('half-star.gif')
    end
    output.html_safe
  end
end
```

Comment: How would I do this with two different star images? I have star.png that I'm guessing would replace the asterisk and star_half.png that would replace the plus, but I'm not sure how to get them to display? Thanks for answering

Comment: I changed the code so that it uses an image to display.

Comment: That doesn't show the stars, it displays:

<img src="star.png"><img src="star.png"><img src="star.png">

On the page

Comment: Please try it again with the updated code. You need to put the images into app/assets/images/ directory.

Comment: Did you use the updated code? I updated it multiple times and you need the very last version.

Comment: Just added it in, it's now not displaying anything, made sure the image names are correct and everything's fine. I don't understand why it's not finding the images

Comment: I'd like to help you by chat but for that you'll need 20 reputation. In case you have some loose ends on other questions now would be a good time to accept answers. That'll push you to the 20.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68593/discussion-between-benjs-1-and-wintermeyer).

Comment: I'm waiting in the chat room.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with something like this:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def render_stars(value)
    i_value = value.floor
    f_value = value - i_value

    output = '*' * i_value
    output << image_tag('half_star.jpg') if f_value > 0

    output
  end

end
```

You might have to use `.html_safe` in the view.

Your `html.erb` snippet looks wrong, however. It won't render correctly, and it will raise an error if you don't close the first `if` somewhere down the file. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: That doesn't work, it displays this in the view: Star rating: ***<img alt="Star half" src="/assets/star_half.png" /> rather than the actual star image

Comment: yes. you have to call `html_safe`, as I said. Like this: `render_stars(value).html_safe`